# Concrete class not being constructed

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual bool foo() const = 0;
    static Base& getHeadInstance();
};

class Concrete: public Base {
public:
    explicit Concrete(Base& f): fwd(f) {}

    // ... other member functions elided
    bool foo() const override { return /* some calculation */ && fwd.foo(); }
private:
    Base& fwd;
};
```

so that I can construct a series of instances like this:

```
Concrete c1(Base::getHeadInstance());
Concrete c2(c1);
Concrete c3(c2);
```

so that `c3` can make decisions and possibly defer to `c2`, which in turn could defer to `c1` and so on like the `Chain of Responsibility` pattern.

The problem is that `c2` and `c3` are not constructed correctly and their `fwd` member always refers to `Base::getHeadInstance()`.

What is going wrong here and what is the fix for this?

*Update:*

It doesn't matter what the static member returns. Pretend it returns an instance of this:

```
class Head: public Base {
public:
    Head() = default;
private:
    bool foo() const override { return true; }
};
Base& Base::getHeadInstance(){ static Head head; return head; }
```

Comment: The question would be easier to answer if `getHeadInstance` definition were provided. Also, it is not `virtual`, so you will always call base version.

Comment: Beware of using reference member types. They generally make assignment difficult to meaningfully implement and move semantics is even more problematic. When you find yourself using a reference type data member, you'll often be better off using a pointer instead.

Comment: I recommend you add a virtual dtor to the base class, and then use the `override` keyword on `foo` in the derived class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this same problem before. It boils down to overload resolution on your custom constructor `Derived(Base&)` vs the implicitly defined copy constructor `Derived(const Derived&);`, where the implicit copy constructor simply wins. Deleting it does not fix this, it still participates in overload resolution (but it does stop the wrong thing from happening silently).

Here is a reduced example:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base();
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived(Base&);
    Derived(const Derived&); // Implicitly or explicitly declared in any case.
};

Derived getDerived();

void test()
{
    Derived d1 = getDerived();
    Derived d2(d1); // copies
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aoJFlC

There are several ways to get the code to do what you want the way you've written it (see other answers), but I would like to point out that you should take special care to save the next reader of your code from this same confusion you had. A cast to `Base&`, repurposed copy constructor semantics or something like using `Derived(Base*);` will all raise questions in future readers. You can try to solve that through documentation, but chances are somebody misses that and becomes confused. I would suggest making the intent as explicit and visible as possible, for example like this:

```
enum class ConstructFromBase { Tag };

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived(Base&, ConstructFromBase);
    Derived(const Derived&) = delete;
};

Derived getDerived();

void test()
{
    Derived d1 = getDerived();
    Derived d2(d1, ConstructFromBase::Tag);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/QfeuAM

That should communicate the intent very clearly and costs virtually nothing. (There are many other ways to write and name such a tag, mine is probably not the most canonical...)

Comment: I've marked this answer as correct because it explains that the compiler is choosing to write and then use its own copy constructor over the constructor I have provided. In my own code I've chosen to `delete` the copy ctor as suggested here and use a template ctor as suggested by @Shloim.

Answer (score 4):

You have an implicit copy constructor you need to get rid of:

```
Concrete(const Concrete& c) = delete;
```

and you'll have to cast your `c1` and `c2`

```
Concrete c1(Base::getHeadInstance());
Concrete c2((Base&)c1);
Concrete c3((Base&)c2);
```

Your other option is to template the constructor:

```
template<typename T>
Concrete(T& f): fwd(f) {}
```

and then your original code would work (Yay!).

```
Concrete c1(Base::getHeadInstance());
Concrete c2(c1);
Concrete c3(c2);
```

Comment: I tried that and the compiler always wants to use this and complains that it is deleted.

Comment: Deleting the copy constructor does not remove it from overload resolution. You're right about the source of the issue, but the resolution is not correct.

Comment: Once you add the casts, you don't need to delete the copy ctor (except as indication that you should have cast).

Comment: Yes, this answer works. Is there another solution which works with the original code?

Comment: Yeah, template the ctor: `template<typename T> Concrete(T& f): fwd(f) {}`

Comment: Do note that the template constructor is not a copy constructor and you still need to delete the copy constructor in order to stop actual copies.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to provide you own copy constructor that does what you want.  Adding

```
Concrete(Concrete& c): fwd(c) {}
```

Will then make

```
Concrete c1(Base::getHeadInstance());
Concrete c2(c1);
Concrete c3(c2);
```

have `c1.fwd == Base::getHeadInstance()`, `c2.fwd == c1`, and `c3.fwd == c2`

Comment: This is more or less abusing the copy constructor for not copying objects... I would strongly advise against that.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Depends on what `Concrete` is intended to represent. It's already not assignable or moveable in the usual sense, so good old fashion value semantics are already out of the question. No matter what it won't be intuitive to use.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I would argue that "not having value/move" semantics is significantly more common and benign than "copy constructor does not actually copy". But the latter still has its uses occasionally, so in the end it's up to good engineering judgement.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to avoid using *references*; even if I admit it is not isomorphic.

```
class Concrete : public Base {
 public:
  explicit Concrete(Base* f) : fwd(*f) {
    // possibly you want to assert precondition? assert(f)?
  }

 private:
  Base& fwd;  // I would prefer Base* here...
};
```

In that way, you don't risk to call the *implicit copy constructor* of `Concrete`; without override o delete anything.

```
Concrete c1(&Base::getHeadInstance());
Concrete c2(&c1);
Concrete c3(&c2);
```

Comment: This is the option I went with when I ran into this problem (which is why I had it mentioned in my answer :D). It is a compromise between "keep it non-verbose at the call site" and "it won't require intricate knowledge to understand why this works" (whereas determining what happens for the "isomorphic" answers is difficult).